# Getting request query parameters count

Tags: node.js, rest, express

My API server is accepting GET request and parsing the parameters. But I am not able to get count of parameters passed.

```
var express = require('express'),
    https   = require('https');

var app = express();

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.query.name);
};
```

When request is received with the parameters, it displays the data as follows

```
{ id: '123', name: 'joel', age: '45' }
joel
```

But if I try to get the count of parameters passed like

```
console.log(req.query).length;
```

it fails. Kindly help me get the count of parameters passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this..this code worked..

```
app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(Object.keys(req.query).length);
});
```

output:

> { id: '123', name: 'joel', age: '45' }
>
> 3

Comment: Thanks for quick response abdulbarik & Supraj. This solved my problem.

Comment: Hi , One doubt
suppose if we pass id as '' , then how can we do null check ?
if(req.query.id){}else{} . Is this the correct way?

Comment: can you tell me your query params

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use `length` on object type you can easily find it by `Object`

Try this

```
var obj={ id: '123', name: 'joel', age: '45' }

console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
```